# Plot FCM clusters in Matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I can visualize the 2 clusters as the example in this [link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fuzzy/fcm.html):

How can I visualize 3 or 4 clusters in this case? And each clusters has a center and those clusters have different colors.

I have tried this but can not put 3 clusters in 3 different colors:

```
figure
plot(fcmdata(:,1),fcmdata(:,2),'o')
line(fcmdata(index1,1), fcmdata(index1,2), 'linestyle',...
                        'none','marker', 'o','color','g')
                    plot(fcmdata(:,1),fcmdata(:,2),'o')
                    hold on
line(fcmdata(index2,1),fcmdata(index2,2),'linestyle',...
                        'none','marker', 'o','color','r')
plot(fcmdata(:,1),fcmdata(:,2),'o')
hold on
line(fcmdata(index3,1),fcmdata(index3,2),'linestyle',...
                        'none','marker', 'o','color','b')

%line(fcmdata(index4,1),fcmdata(index4,2),'linestyle',...
                       % 'none','marker', 'o','color','c')

 hold on
plot(center(1,1),center(1,2),'kx','markersize',15,'LineWidth',2)
plot(center(2,1),center(2,2),'kx','markersize',15,'LineWidth',2)
plot(center(3,1),center(3,2),'kx','markersize',15,'LineWidth',2)
```

Do I miss anything ? Where can I change the code to plot 3 clusters in 3 different colors?

Comment: You just duplicate the `plot` commands for the new centers, or better yet, put the `plot`s in a loop.

Comment: I put the code like this:

Comment: Please edit the question and add the code there. Everything necessary to answer the question should be in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: @beaker: I have updated the question with code. Could you please tell me where to edit ?

Comment: @beaker: I have updated the question with code. Could you please tell me where to edit ?